# Notepad++: Delete everything in a string after 4 numerals

Tags: notepad++

I have a document with several thousands lines, every line is build like this:

```
somethingRandom#0000 anotherRandomThing
```

0000 represents a random, four digit number. No line is like the other, the only constant are the random numbers. "anotherRandomThing" may contain numbers, but never four in a row.

So my question is, how can I delete everything in a line after exactly 4 (random) numbers? Is there any easy way to do this?

I appreciate any help!

Comment: Using Search replace (Ctrl + H) and by using a regex like the following (.*)([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])(.*) and having nothing in the replace text field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex to replace (Ctrl+H) by nothing:

```
(?<=\d{4}).*?$
```

Remember to check the Regular expression option.
[image: Like this]

Comment: Thank you so much! That was easier than expected.

Comment: Regex is God when working with finding/replacing string.

Comment: Say the part before the numerals does contain 4 or more numbers, how would you edit the string to look for everything after #1234, including the # to make sure nothing that shouldnt be deleted stays ?

Edit: Got it. (?<=#\d{4}).*?$

Comment: Nice try bro :)